# Any more of this $a\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\phi^n}\right)+b\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\phi^m}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}$ type?

Tags: trigonometry

$$\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\phi}\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\phi^3}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

$$2\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\phi^2}\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\phi^6}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

$$3\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\phi^3}\right)+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\phi^5}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

**Is there more of this type that yeild** $\frac{\pi}{4}$ or these are the only answers?

Where $a,b,m,n \ge 1$ are all integers

$$a\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\phi^n}\right)+b\arctan\left(\frac{1}{\phi^m}\right)=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

I look through many sites, but couldn't find any. If you do come across please let me know. Please no square root involved.

Comment: @Arthur Presumably yes, since the three equations hold for the golden ratio.

Comment: @almagest Based on some numerical attempts, I would be more pessimistic than you...

Comment: @JeanMarie Arthur's question has now been deleted. He asked if $\phi$ was the golden ratio. I have no opinion on whether there are other relations of the same type!

Comment: Not quite what you want, but $${\pi\over4}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\arctan(F_{2n+1}^{-1})$$ where $F_n$ are the Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Thank you for your effort @GerryMyerson

Comment: I checked $0<a,b,m,n<20$ and there are no others except those three.